# Validate php form fail

Tags: php, validation

This code works fine in seperated file named form.php, but when i paste it to 
wordpress theme page it does not even validate form and not even send mail of course. Why is there no any action after i clikced submit button in wordpress theme?
Anyone can help me to solve problem?

```
  get_header();

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $nameError = $mailError = $messageError = '';

    function validate($data){
        if(empty($data)){
            return false;
        }else{
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
    }

  //Validate name input
    if(!validate($_POST['name'])){
      $nameError = 'Polje ime je obavezno.';
    }else{
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['name'])) {
            $nameError = "Polje moze sadrzavati samo slova i razmak"; 
        }
    }

 //Validate email input
    if(!validate($_POST['email'])){
        $mailError = 'Polje email je obavezno';
    }else{
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $mailError = "Nevazeća email adresa"; 
         }
    }

 //Validate message textarea
    if(!validate($_POST['message'])){
        $messageError = 'Molimo unesite poruku';
    }

 if(empty($nameError) && empty($mailError) && empty($messageError)){
        //Create the body
        $body = "Ime: {$_POST['name']}\n\nPoruka: {$_POST['message']}";

        //Make it no longer than 70 characters long 
        $body = wordwrap($body, 70);

        //Send the mail
        mail('example@example.com', 'Contact Form Submission', 
     $body, 
    "From: {$_POST['email']}");

        //Print a message 
        echo '<p><em>Thank you for contacting me. I will reply some day. 
     </em></p>';
      }else{
        echo '<p style="font-weight: bold; color: #C00">Please fill out 
 the 
     form completley.</p>';
      }   
  }
```

**HTML** Code that is placed in same file as php validation

```
        <section class="contact-img">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
         <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>

 <section class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('contact-page'); ?>  
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4 class="col-xs-12 text-center"><strong>Ostavite 
  poruku</strong></h4>     
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  
value="" placeholder="Ime">
                    <div><?php if(isset($nameError)) echo $nameError; ?> 
 </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" 
 value="" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <div><span class="error"><?php if(isset($mailError)) 
 echo $mailError; ?></span></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" 
  placeholder="Poruka"></textarea>
                    <div><span class="error"><?php 
  if(isset($messageError)) echo $messageError; ?></span></div>
                </div>

                <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="button" 
  value="Pošalji">
            </form>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: can you share any error that is showing during submit of form?

Comment: `$nameError = 'Polje moze sadrzavati samo slova i razmak;` <--- missing `'`, also your name Regex should include a hyphen, some ppl have hyphenated last names.  Personally I would do this `/^[\w\s]+$/` or `/^\w+\s+\w+$/` so that its `first last` not `f i r s t l a s t` .  For a middle name you could do `/^(\w+)\s+(?1)(?:\s(?1))?$/`

Comment: `$nameError = 'Polje moze sadrzavati samo slova i razmak;` is indeed missing the closing `'`

Comment: @ErikGiberti - yes it is indeed missing `'`, `$nameError = 'Polje moze sadrzavati samo slova i razmak;`

Comment: I forgot to add ( ' ) when i was retyping code, but that was not problem, problem is when i paste this code in wordpress theme page and it does do nothing after i press submit button. but in separated file it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error (white page of death, if error reporting is off)

```
$nameError = 'Polje moze sadrzavati samo slova i razmak;
```

Should be:

```
$nameError = 'Polje moze sadrzavati samo slova i razmak';
```

Another thing that might get you is your name validation Regex is to simple, it doesn't account for things like `Jane Doe-Smith`, or `J o h n S m i t h` or `j` or even `''`, an empty string.

I would use something like this:

```
if(!preg_match("/^([a-z]+)\s+(?:([a-z]+)\s+)?([-a-z]+)$/i" ,  $_POST['name'])){
        $nameError = 'Polje moze sadrzavati samo slova i razmak;
}
```

Regex:

- `([a-z]+)` matches `a` though `z` (first 2 capture groups)
- `\s+` matches one or more space
- `(?...)` non-capture group `?` optionally, middle name
- `([-a-z]+)` matches `-` and `a` though `z` (for hyphenated last names)
- `\i` case insensitive flag.

[Regex Test](https://regex101.com/r/sbuCKa/2)

Test cases:

```
John Smith {match}
John E Smith {match}
Jane J Doe-Smith {match}
John {no match}
```

Which is still a small sample size, but should cover most English names ( not sure what language this is `Polje moze`).

I once dated a girl many many years ago with a hyphenated last name ... lol.

The last thing is to turn on display errors and set error reporting to a value like `E_ALL` (for development).  I'd say use `ini_set('display_errors', '1')` and `error_reporting()`  but they won't catch syntax errors in the same file (generally).

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add ( ' ) when i was retyping code, but regEx is not problem or ( ' ), problem is that form does nothhing after i press submit button

Comment: did you try it without the `action` in the form tag, if your sending it to itself you can just omit it.

Comment: I solved problem, it was in input tag attribute button, and should be submit! And this is Bosnian language. we do not use hyphenated names :)